# Using ES6 Template Literals in a Javascript script on a STRUCTR page

Tags: javascript, structr

I am trying to serve a collapsible tree diagram from my STRUCTR 2.01 app to describe a hierarchical section of my graph.
I based the page on [this example](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd)

The page correctly serves the nodes but cannot parse the paths.
These are defined in the javascript using ES6 template literals.

When I serve the same page directly (i.e. not from STRUCTR) and view in the same browser etc. it works fine.

Is STRUCTR blocking or incorrectly interpreting the javascript template literals ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any content served by Structr, any text enclosed in `${...}` is treated as an expression to be interpreted by Structr (we call it StructrScript) serverside.

Seems to be a conflict with ES6 Template Expressions.

As a workaround, you can put the JavaScript code in a file where it's not interpreted by Structr.

Comment: Excellent. That worked perfectly. Thank you.
If you get a chance to add an example to the knowledge graph of how to feed D3-Hierarchy functions with data from Structr I would really appreciate it.